# What is Intraclass Distance?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, distance

For an assignment I have to compute the intra-class distance and use it as an objective function to select features. This is for the MNIST dataset.

While I have a fairly good handle on other aspects of this assignment, the term intra-class distance is confusing to me. Google does not result in any concrete answers either.

I understand *intra* would mean within, but that's exactly what is confusing to me: how can distance be within? Is it the distance of each measurement with another?

For example, I have N measurements for Class C. Is intra-class distance the distance from n to N-1 measurements within that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Intraclass distance is the distance between two points that are in the same class.***

In your example, an *intra*-class distance is the distance between measurements $X_i$ and $X_j$ where $(i,j \in 1 \cdots N)$, and $X_i$ and $X_j$ are members of class C. One usually takes an average over the distances from all possible $(i,j)$ pairs within class C, and use it as the objective function. You can also use the distance between $X_i$ and $\bar{X}_C$ (the average coordinate of all measurements in class C), and take the average of this over all measurements in class C.

In contrast, an *inter*-class distance is the distance between measurements $X_i$ and $X_j$, where $X_i$ and $X_j$ are members of different classes.

Comment: Thank you! I note that you mention one usually takes an average over the all the pairwise distances from class C. My assignment states that "Implement a forward search algorithm using the Intra-class distance (defined by the mean of
each class)" - does this mean I take the distance of each point from the mean?

Comment: Yes. It means what you said.